# Calling a Service in Periodical Intervals

Tags: wcf, iis

I Want a service call to happen whenever another service was started.

Here is the Scenario.  I have a WCF service called abc.svc hosted on IIS. I want a method called "MyMethod" from xyz.svc to get called when abc service is hosted & from then On I want "MyMethod" to trigger at periodic intervals.

Tried calling the "MyMethod" in the Appplcation_start event of abc. But I am getting Endpoint not found exceptiopn when trying to create a serviceclient for the service xyz.svc. Can some one suggest the best solution to this use case.